# restarting a database

Tags: mysql, database, connection, restart

where do i type in the commands to restart a mysql database?

Is it in a PHP file? or into the database itself? I use Heidi SQL to connect to a database.

commands like these

```
= killall -9 mysqld
= service mysql stop
=cp var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock_backup
= rm -f /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
= service mysql start
= ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
= /scripts/restartsrv mysql
```

because im getting this error

```
     Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to restart the database? It shouldn't be required to be done automaticly.

If you happend to mess up the database, you can restart it through the terminal (ubuntu etc.) I'm not sure how much you know about the terminals, but you should be able to learn more about them, else ask your webprovider how to do it.

If you rely on restarting your database on a schedule, something in your code clearly does something wrong with the database and should be fixed.

[Examples](http://theos.in/desktop-linux/tip-that-matters/how-do-i-restart-mysql-server/)

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld restart
# or
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Comment: Thanks, it was the code but other people were leading me in the wrong direction which led me to asking this question :) thanks again